# Exponentiating cubic functions (and so on)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

The exponential distribution follows from exponentiating a linear function, while the normal distribution follows from exponentiating a quadratic function. Do the distributions that follow from exponentiating functions of 3rd or higher degree have names or uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such distributions would be part of the [exponential family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family). I don't think they have a special name, though.